# You can extend the IntSummaryStatistics class?

Tags: java, java-stream, summary

I'm using the Java stream statistics, using the speedment, this way:

```java
IntSummaryStatistics intSummary = join.stream(). MapToInt (t> t.get0(). GetCNationkey ()). SummaryStatistics();
Long sumResult = intSummary.getSum ();
```

I wanted a new class to construct a new `getSum()` method. Something like:

```java
IntSummaryStatisticsTest intSummarytest = join.stream (). MapToInt (t> t.get0 (). GetCNationkey ()). SummaryStatistics ();
Long sumResult = intSummarytest.getSumTest();
```

I tried to create a new class:

```java
public class IntSummaryStatisticsTest extends IntSummaryStatistics {}

IntSummaryStatisticsTest summa = join.stream().mapToInt(t->t.get0().getCNationkey()).summaryStatistics();
```

but I got this error: `incompatible types required java. Required: IntSummaryStatisticsTest Found: java.util.IntSummaryStatistics`.

Is it possible to implement this new `getSumTest()` method?

Comment: I would prefer composition over inheritance and accept an `IntSummaryStatistics` object as a parameter in your constructor, which you can initialize via: `var stats = new IntSummaryStatisticsTest(join.stream().mapToInt(t->t.get0().getCNationkey()).summaryStatistics());`

Comment: How can I do this ? @JacobG.

Comment: If no one else answers this within the next hour, I'll write out an example for you as an answer

Comment: Can you provide your example? @JacobG.

Comment: Sure, I saw this question was answered and didn't think you needed it anymore, but give me a bit and I will :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Like I stated in the comments, I'd opt for composition over inheritance. This means that you can create your class, `IntSummaryStatisticsTest`, and accept an `IntSummaryStatistics` object as a parameter in your constructor. Your class would look something like the following:

```
class IntSummaryStatisticsTest {
    private final IntSummaryStatistics statistics;

    public IntSummaryStatisticsTest(IntSummaryStatistics statistics) {
        this.statistics = statistics;
    }

    public long getSumTest() {
        // return your value
    }
}
```

The usage of the class would look like:

```
var summary = new IntSummaryStatisticsTest(join.stream()
        .mapToInt(t -> t.get0().getCNationkey())
        .summaryStatistics());

System.out.println(summary.getSumTest());
```

Comment: Just a note: this (eventually) does not work if the `accept` method needs to be overwritten, that is, when the data collection from the original `IntSummaryStatistics` must be changed/complemented

Answer (score 1):

The [documentation of `IntStream`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/12/docs/api/java.base/java/util/IntSummaryStatistics.html) gives a hint:

> ...For example, you can compute summary statistics on a stream of ints with:
>
> ```
> IntSummaryStatistics stats = intStream.collect(
>     IntSummaryStatistics::new,
>     IntSummaryStatistics::accept,
>     IntSummaryStatistics::combine);
> ```

you should be able to do the same with `IntSummaryStatisticsTest`, that is:

```
IntSummaryStatisticsTest stats = intStream.collect(
    IntSummaryStatisticsTest::new,
    IntSummaryStatisticsTest::accept,
    IntSummaryStatisticsTest::combine);
```

*But also consider Jacob's comment/solution (using composition would probably be even better)*

Comment: ```
IntSummaryStatisticsTest stats = IntStream.collect(
                IntSummaryStatistics::new,
                IntSummaryStatistics::accept,
                IntSummaryStatistics::combine); ``` This does not work :(

Comment: You should use `IntSummaryStatisticsTest::new`. The code he provides is the actual implementation of the `summaryStatistics()` method. You have to modify that to fit your needs.

Comment: I am just quoting the documentation....and I hought that "...do the same with `IntSummaryStatisticsTest`" is clear enough - edited

Comment: I have this error: Error:(74, 56) java: non-static method <R>collect(java.util.function.Supplier<R>,java.util.function.ObjIntConsumer<R>,java.util.function.BiConsumer<R,R>) cannot be referenced from a static context

Comment: `IntSummaryStatisticsTest summa = join.stream().mapToInt(t -> t.get0().GetCNationkey()).collect(IntSummaryStatisticsTest::new,
                IntSummaryStatisticsTest::accept,
                IntSummaryStatisticsTest::combine);`